# jquerymobile list view rounded corners issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Please refer to http://m.xn--e-nsker-r1a.dk/ to see the problem in real life.

Can anyone tell me why initially (even after I have tried calling `$(".todoList").listview('refresh')` the corners are not round. The list items are fully styled, but the corners are not round.

Then if I add a todoitem (clicking the `+`), the corners become round, but if i remove it again No corners are round. I would expect it that the bottom corners could have difficulty staying round since the listitem was removed from the bottom, but even the top, that has undergone no manipulation has square corners after the remove of the listitem - even though they became round after the listitem was originally added.

This makes no sense to me, why would `listview('refresh')` make the corners square

Thank you.

Comment: You will have to copy/paste the link as StackOverflow does not like the `ø` character.

Comment: @Jasper - thank you for your reply - i changed the link to the encoded version. It should now be accesible, you can see the mobile page both from mobile and normal browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's something in you mobilescript.js thats messes with the css/layout.

Here is a jsfiddle without it: http://jsfiddle.net/NABUv/1/

And here is one with it: http://jsfiddle.net/NABUv/2/

You can see the missing border if you use google chrome/a webkit browser

So it's not JqueryMobile :)

Comment: I chose the ugly hack, and coded the css for rounded corners in mobilestyle.css

Answer (score 3):

listview('refresh', true);

The additional true parameter keeps the rounding effect.

Comment: This seems to work for me. Do you know what the second parameter is? I can't find any documentation for it on the jqm site.

Comment: Worked only partly in my case. Rounded corners stayed, but css styles of items went weird, getting really "thick" for lack of a better word.

Answer (score 1):

See that whether have you specified data-inset="true" for the  Tag.

Thanks,
Shyam

Comment: Checked my listview. It has data-inset="true" but problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem, turned out that I had a hidden div element before + after my page content. JqueryMobile css uses first-child + last-child selectors to apply the border-radius.